# jQuery/javascript - can't find a way to avoid code adding a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently modifying the [FlexNav Plugin](http://jasonweaver.name/lab/flexiblenavigation/). Instead of hovering to open the sub-menus, I changed it to open by click.

The problem now is that it takes two clicks to open a submenu.

I understand the problem is the fact that the code adds the class "flexnav-show" to the submenu ul when the menu is opened intitially. A click on the submenu trigger then removes this class, which causes nothing, and a second click add it again opening the submenu.

If anyone can point me to the right place in the code where i can avoid adding the class on all ul's. Or, if someone has a better idea...

```
$.fn.flexNav = function(options) {
var $nav, $top_nav_items, breakpoint, count, nav_percent, nav_width, resetMenu, resizer, settings, showMenu, toggle_selector, touch_selector;
settings = $.extend({
  'animationSpeed': 250,
  'transitionOpacity': true,
  'buttonSelector': '.menu-button',
  'hoverIntent': false,
  'hoverIntentTimeout': 150,
  'calcItemWidths': false,
  'hover': false
}, options);
$nav = $(this);
$nav.addClass('with-js');
if (settings.transitionOpacity === true) {
  $nav.addClass('opacity');
}
$nav.find("li").each(function() {
  if ($(this).has("ul").length) {
    return $(this).addClass("item-with-ul").find("ul").hide();
  }
});
if (settings.calcItemWidths === true) {
  $top_nav_items = $nav.find('>li');
  count = $top_nav_items.length;
  nav_width = 100 / count;
  nav_percent = nav_width + "%";
}
if ($nav.data('breakpoint')) {
  breakpoint = $nav.data('breakpoint');
}
showMenu = function() {
  if ($nav.hasClass('lg-screen') === true && settings.hover === true) {
    if (settings.transitionOpacity === true) {
      return $(this).find('>ul').addClass('flexnav-show').stop(true, true).animate({
        height: ["toggle", "swing"],
        opacity: "toggle"
      }, settings.animationSpeed);
    } else {
      return $(this).find('>ul').addClass('flexnav-show').stop(true, true).animate({
        height: ["toggle", "swing"]
      }, settings.animationSpeed);
    }
  }
};
resetMenu = function() {
  if ($nav.hasClass('lg-screen') === true && $(this).find('>ul').hasClass('flexnav-show') === true && settings.hover === true) {
    if (settings.transitionOpacity === true) {
      return $(this).find('>ul').removeClass('flexnav-show').stop(true, true).animate({
        height: ["toggle", "swing"],
        opacity: "toggle"
      }, settings.animationSpeed);
    } else {
      return $(this).find('>ul').removeClass('flexnav-show').stop(true, true).animate({
        height: ["toggle", "swing"]
      }, settings.animationSpeed);
    }
  }
};
resizer = function() {
  var selector;
  if ($(window).width() <= breakpoint) {
    $nav.removeClass("lg-screen").addClass("sm-screen");
    if (settings.calcItemWidths === true) {
      $top_nav_items.css('width', '100%');
    }
    selector = settings['buttonSelector'] + ', ' + settings['buttonSelector'] + ' .touch-button';
    $(selector).removeClass('active');
    return $('.one-page li a').on('click', function() {
      return $nav.removeClass('flexnav-show');
    });
  } else if ($(window).width() > breakpoint) {
    $nav.removeClass("sm-screen").addClass("lg-screen");
    if (settings.calcItemWidths === true) {
      $top_nav_items.css('width', nav_percent);
    }
    $nav.removeClass('flexnav-show').find('.item-with-ul').on();
    $('.item-with-ul').find('ul').removeClass('flexnav-show');
    resetMenu();
    if (settings.hoverIntent === true) {
      return $('.item-with-ul').hoverIntent({
        over: showMenu,
        out: resetMenu,
        timeout: settings.hoverIntentTimeout
      });
    } else if (settings.hoverIntent === false) {
      return $('.item-with-ul').on('mouseenter', showMenu).on('mouseleave', resetMenu);
    }
  }
};
$(settings['buttonSelector']).data('navEl', $nav);
touch_selector = '.item-with-ul, ' + settings['buttonSelector'];
$(touch_selector).append('<span class="touch-button"><i class="navicon">&#9660;</i></span>');
toggle_selector = settings['buttonSelector'] + ', ' + settings['buttonSelector'] + ' .touch-button';
$(toggle_selector).on('click', function(e) {
  var $btnParent, $thisNav, bs;
  $(toggle_selector).toggleClass('active');
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  bs = settings['buttonSelector'];
  $btnParent = $(this).is(bs) ? $(this) : $(this).parent(bs);
  $thisNav = $btnParent.data('navEl');
  return $thisNav.toggleClass('flexnav-show');
});
$('.touch-button').on('click', function(e) {
  var $sub, $touchButton;
  $sub = $(this).parent('.item-with-ul').find('>ul');
  $touchButton = $(this).parent('.item-with-ul').find('>span.touch-button');
  if ($nav.hasClass('lg-screen') === true) {
    $(this).parent('.item-with-ul').siblings().find('ul.flexnav-show').removeClass('flexnav-show').hide();
  }
  if ($sub.hasClass('flexnav-show') === true) {
    $sub.removeClass('flexnav-show').slideUp(settings.animationSpeed);
    return $touchButton.removeClass('active');
  } else if ($sub.hasClass('flexnav-show') === false) {
    $sub.addClass('flexnav-show').slideDown(settings.animationSpeed);
    return $touchButton.addClass('active');
  }
});
$nav.find('.item-with-ul *').focus(function() {
  $(this).parent('.item-with-ul').parent().find(".open").not(this).removeClass("open").hide();
  return $(this).parent('.item-with-ul').find('>ul').addClass("open").show();
});
resizer();
return $(window).on('resize', resizer);
```

};

Answer (score 0):

The code adds the class 'flexnav-show' in line 34 to all child 'ul' nodes.

The code is in action when the **function showMenu** is called.

Comment: what about replacing line 34 code with: 

`return $(this).find('>ul.level_1').addClass('flexnav-show').stop(true, true).animate({
        height: ["toggle", "swing"]
      }, settings.animationSpeed); `

Comment: Didn't change anything... class stil gets added to both ul's.